# How to sort result by highest value, using 2 columns?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a lot of users with websites and I want to select all websites and sort them by visitor amount. The users can specify the visitor amount in 2 ways. Either they can input it manually as a string that is stored in fb.visitor in the query below.

The second way is that he user install a Javascript Tracking Code on their site that then adds entries to the table tracking_visits and the total amount of visits is count(tv.id) below.

I want to be able to sort this result in 2 ways.

1) I want to get the highest result on top and lowest at bottom, using both columns. Example the Result should be:

- 99'947 ( COUNT(tv.id) )
- 75'412 ( COUNT(tv.id) )
- 40'000 ( fb.visitors  )
- 37'482 ( COUNT(tv.id) )
- 30'000 ( fb.visitors  )

2) Second sort I would like to be able to get all COUNT(tv.id) on top, highest first, and then get fb.visitors with highest first below. Example:

- 99'947 ( COUNT(tv.id) )
- 75'412 ( COUNT(tv.id) )
- 37'482 ( COUNT(tv.id) )
- 40'000 ( fb.visitors  )
- 30'000 ( fb.visitors  )

My current Query looks like this:

```
SELECT cs.userid, fb.visitors, COUNT( tv.id ) 
FROM campaigns_signups cs
INNER JOIN fe_blogs fb ON cs.userid = fb.userid
INNER JOIN tracking_visits tv ON tv.blogid = cs.userid
WHERE tv.visitdate
BETWEEN  "2013-09-04"
AND  "2013-10-04"
AND cs.campaignid =  "97"
AND cs.status <  "4"
GROUP BY tv.blogid
ORDER BY COUNT( tv.id ) , fb.visitors DESC
```

Note that the Dates  and Integers in the Query is just examples.

The problem with this query is that it only selects the result that has entries in tracking_visits. I want to select a result where I get BOTH bloggers who have visitor amount in tracking_visits AND blogs who have visitor amount in fb.visitors.

Answer (score 1):

For your first task, you can use `ORDER BY GREATEST(COUNT(tv.id), fb.visitors) DESC`. [Documentation on GREATEST.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_greatest) For your second, you will want to use `UNION`. [Documentation on UNION.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html)

If for your first task you want each site to yield two rows (one for the greatest of the two values and the other for the least), you can again achieve this using `UNION`.

Comment: for his second he can use a case

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for `greatest`

```
select greatest(ifnull(fb.visitors,0),count(tv_id)) from.... order by 1

select greatest(ifnull(fb.visitors,0),count(tv_id)) from.... 
order by 
case when greatest(ifnull(fb.visitors,0),count(tv_id))=fb.bisitors then 2 else 1 end, greatest(ifnull(fb.visitors,0),count(tv_id))
```

the second order by case orders by source of value and then by value size

Answer (score 0):

For the second option of selecting the COUNT(tv.id) first, I was able to accomplish this by the following query:

```
SELECT *, tv.tracked_visits
FROM campaigns_signups cs
INNER JOIN fe_blogs fb ON cs.userid = fb.userid

LEFT JOIN (    
SELECT blogid, COUNT( id ) AS  "tracked_visits"
FROM tracking_visits
WHERE visitdate
BETWEEN  "2013-09-04"
AND  "2013-10-04"                                               
GROUP BY blogid
) AS tv ON tv.blogid = cs.userid
WHERE cs.campaignid =  :campaignid
AND cs.status <  :status
ORDER BY tv.tracked_visits DESC , fb.visitors DESC
```